# Get longitude , latitude and name of place from place picker

Tags: java, android, google-places

I dont know why but place picker open in android mobile but immediately closes after 2 or 3 seconds automatically. I enable places api key in my developers console and also restrict it to mobile app by giving package name and sha 1 .Every thing is fine but dont know from last many hours that why it cant work.

Here i can send code detail of my project.Please help me I tried alot of times but can't get any solution.,

Here is the dependencies that i implement in gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

And code for main activity is given below :

```
package com.spotech.placepickerdemo;

    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button btnPlacePicker;
        TextView txtLongitude,txtLatitude;
        int PLACEPICKER_REQUEST = 1 ;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            btnPlacePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlacePicker);
            txtLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitudeplace);
            txtLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitudeplace);


            btnPlacePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

                    try {
                        Intent intent = builder.build(MainActivity.this);
                        startActivityForResult(intent,PLACEPICKER_REQUEST);
                    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        e.toString();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            if (resultCode == PLACEPICKER_REQUEST){
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data,this);
                    String lat = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().latitude);
                    String lon = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().longitude);
                    String placeName = String.valueOf(place.getName());
                    txtLatitude.setText( "Latitude : "+ lat);
                    txtLongitude.setText("Longitude : "+lon);
                    Toast.makeText(this, placeName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        }
    }
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.spotech.placepickerdemo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBQHVoCdqQsRFP23dK9lENxEtZb0o3k1mw"
            />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

here is my logcat debugger

```
2020-03-20 16:27:11.094 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/ViewRootImpl@2abc404[MainActivity]: stopped(false) old=false
2020-03-20 16:27:11.106 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/ViewRootImpl@2abc404[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
2020-03-20 16:27:11.107 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@8cab16b[MainActivity]
2020-03-20 16:27:11.107 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-03-20 16:27:11.108 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@8cab16b[MainActivity]
2020-03-20 16:27:11.108 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-03-20 16:27:11.108 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2020-03-20 16:27:11.108 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2020-03-20 16:27:11.111 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=72
2020-03-20 16:28:10.858 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/ViewRootImpl@2abc404[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
2020-03-20 16:28:10.966 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/ViewRootImpl@2abc404[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
2020-03-20 16:28:11.421 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/ViewRootImpl@2abc404[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
2020-03-20 16:28:11.535 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/ViewRootImpl@2abc404[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
2020-03-20 16:28:11.581 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/ViewRootImpl@2abc404[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
2020-03-20 16:28:11.581 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@8cab16b[MainActivity]
2020-03-20 16:28:11.581 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-03-20 16:28:11.748 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=72
2020-03-20 16:28:12.195 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/ViewRootImpl@2abc404[MainActivity]: stopped(false) old=false
2020-03-20 16:28:12.207 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/ViewRootImpl@2abc404[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
2020-03-20 16:28:12.207 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@8cab16b[MainActivity]
2020-03-20 16:28:12.207 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-03-20 16:28:12.210 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@8cab16b[MainActivity]
2020-03-20 16:28:12.210 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2020-03-20 16:28:12.210 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2020-03-20 16:28:12.210 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2020-03-20 16:28:12.212 26522-26522/com.spotech.placepickerdemo D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=71
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with "immediately closes after 2 or 3 seconds"? Do you have some error prints in logcat? If yes, please put those in your question!

Comment: @Gabriel14 Please wait i will send it to you

Comment: 2020-03-20 16:27:07.776 26522-26522/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-03-20 16:27:07.778 26522-26522/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1

@Ga

Comment: @Gabriel14 this is shown in my logcat error

Comment: Don't write it in comment, edit you question and add it :)

Comment: The Place Picker was deprecated on January 29, 2019. It was turned off on July 29, 2019, and is no longer available. Continued use will result in an error message. The new SDK does not support the Place Picker.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir 
So what can i implement to search place ang get name, latitude and longitude of searched place

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir kindly guide me about my solution

Comment: @MughiraDar follow this [doc](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) what you are looking for here

Comment: thanks for your guideness and time 
im trying to acheive this Thanks

Comment: Whenever you need help please don’t hesitate to ask.